# Page refresh with post request

Tags: javascript

In our application, we need to refresh the page. Now I am using the `onclick()` event to call the below javascript method.

```
function refresh() {
    document.getElementById('Question-Preview-ComboBox').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('Question-Preview-RelatedSRTicketDetails').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('Question-Preview-SignoffdetailControl').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('Question-Preview-RelatedTicketDetails').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('Question-Preview-PerformedBy').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('Question-Preview-TextBox').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('Question-Preview-CheckBoxMatrix').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('Question-Preview-Radio').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('Question-Preview-CheckBoxMatrixWOT').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('Question-Preview-MultiLineText').style.display='none';

    if (windowDirty == true) {
        showModal('doyouwanttosave');
    }
    else {
        self.location = 'CreateQuestionnaireForm.html';
    }
}
```

The above script will ask users before they refresh the page "Do you want to save" and will make a GET request to call the controller method to reload the page. But our requirement is to change the GET request to POST for the above same functionality. Please suggest how can I change a GET request to POST?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to create a hidden form, add it to the document and then submit it by calling the `.submit()` on the form's DOM object.

Answer (score 2):

Include the form tag and specify the action method as post

```
    <form action="destination_url" METHOD=Post>
     ....

   <input type=submit value="Submit" />
   </form>
```

Comment: In my jsp I am using the post method only, like below :<form:form method="post" action="add.html"
  modelAttribute="questionnaire" id="createQuestionform"
  onsubmit="return validate(this);" class="form_createQuestionnaireForm">

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a form and submit it - than you'll have post request.

Comment: I have jsp with a form tag having an action with the post request. but Submit will call the different controller method.

Comment: you can add your own form and submit it